# How to programmatically go to the next screen in the MSI installer from a custom action?

Tags: c++, wix, windows-installer

I have a WiX custom dialog `ConfigDlg` with my own controls in it:

```
  <Fragment>    
    <UI Id="My_WixUI_Mondo">

      <Publish Dialog="ConfigDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomizeDlg">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="ConfigDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>

    </UI>
  </Fragment>
```

I need to program the Next button to check what user entered in my ConfigDlg and disallow the "Next" screen if such check fails. So I changed my XML to call my `idCA_NextBtn` custom action as such:

```
  <Fragment>    
    <UI Id="My_WixUI_Mondo">

      <Publish Dialog="ConfigDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomizeDlg">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="ConfigDlg" Control="Next" Event="DoAction" Value="idCA_NextBtn">1</Publish>

    </UI>
  </Fragment>
```

where:

```
<Binary Id="caBinDll" SourceFile="$(var.SourceFldrBld)ca_Installer.dll" />
<CustomAction Id="idCA_NextBtn" Execute="immediate" BinaryKey="caBinDll" DllEntry="caNextButton" Return="check" />
```

My `caNextButton` function in the custom action DLL gets called, but I'm not sure how to advance to the next screen (or `VerifyReadyDlg`) from it:

```
extern "C" UINT APIENTRY caNextButton(MSIHANDLE hInstall)
{
    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

Or to simulate?

```
  <Publish Dialog="ConfigDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controls can have multiple ControlEvents (publish elements) and they are processed in order.  What you do is have the custom action called first and have it set a SomeProperty to null or 1 then have two mutually exclusive events.

publish DoAction CustomActionName   Condition 1  (true/always)

publish SpawnDialog CustomBrandedMessageBoxDialog  Condition Not SomeProperty

publish NewDialog VerifyReadyDlgCondition SomeProperty